# Trying to change or interpret the C code to python

Tags: python, c

So I am trying to change the C code to python. I am not sure how to do this. Basic idea is that I am trying to convert AA letter to numeric cod(0-21)

This is what I tried to do

```
def annum(ch):
    const_aacvs = ['999','0','3','4','3','6','13','7','8','9','21','11','10','12','2','21','14','5','1','15','16','21','19','17','21','18','6']
    return(ch.isalpha() ? aacvs[ch & 30] : 20)
```

it shows invalid syntax. I know it has to be a simple problem.

this is the original code from the C

```
int annum(int ch){
    const static int accvs[] = {999, 0, 3, 4, 3, 6, 13, 7, 8, 9, 21, 11, 10, 12, 2, 21, 14, 5, 1, 15, 16, 21, 19, 17, 21, 18, 6};

    return(isalpha(ch) ? accvs[ch & 30] : 20)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the thing is, Python does not have the same ternary operator.

```
condition?true:false => true if condition else false
```

To implement the line:

```
return(isalpha(ch) ? accvs[ch & 30] : 20)
```

in python, you have to do the following:

```
return (accvs[ord(ch) & 30] if ch.isalpha() else '20')
```

Answer (score 0):

I see three problems here:

1. In the C code, `accvs` is an array of numbers. In the Python code, `const_aacvs` is an array of strings -- and the variable name is (mis)spelled inconsistently.
2. The C code depends on `char`'s identity as a numeric type. The Python code expects `ch` to be a string, but does not take any steps to convert it to a number before using it to index into `const_aacvs`. Use `ord()` to perform this conversion.
3. There is no `?:` operator in Python. Use `a if c else b` as a ternary, but mind that the operands come in a different order.

Answer (score 0):

```
def annum(ch):
    acvs = [999,0,3,4,3,6,13,7,8,9,21,11,10,12,2,21,14,5,1,15,16,21,19,17,21,18,6]
    return aacvs[ord(ch) & 30] if ch.isalpha() else 20
```

Comment: That won't work either. `ch` must be a string for `ch.isalpha` to exist, so `ch & 30` will throw a TypeError.